# Have An Application Open In The Workspace It Was Originally Opened In

Tags: xubuntu, workspaces, personalization

When I open an application in workspace1 and then change to workspace2 before the application finishes loading, it will open in workspace2. I want it to open in workspace1, where I opened it. How would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution:

- Open Settings Manager

  Open Windows Manger Tweaks

  Focus

  Click Do nothing under "when a window raises itself:"